# I'm trying to retrieve a file from the internet, extract it, load it into pandas and display the first five rows

Tags: python, pandas, operating-system

My problem is that the file and folders aren't retrieved, also the directory isn't created.
fetching the data from the internet

```
import os
import tarfile
from six.moves import urllib

DOWNLOAD_ROOT = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ageron/handson-ml/master"
HOUSING_PATH = os.path.join("datasets", "housing")
HOUSING_URL = DOWNLOAD_ROOT + "datasets/housing/housing.tgz"

def fetch_housing_data(housing_url=HOUSING_URL, housing_path=HOUSING_PATH):
  if not os.path.isdir(housing_path):
    os.makedirs(housing_path)
  tgz_path = os.path.join(housing_path, "housing.tgz")
  urllib.request.urlretrieve(housing_url, tgz_path)
  housing_tgz = tarfile.open(tgz_path)
  housing_tgz.extractall(path=housing_path)
  housing_tgz.close()
```

**This is where i'll be loading the data into pandas**

```
import pandas as pd

def load_housing_data(housing_path=HOUSING_PATH):
  csv_path = os.path.join(housing_path, "housing.csv")
  return pd.read_csv(csv_path)
```

**Retrieving the first five rows**

```
housing = load_housing_data()
housing.head()
```

**This is the error I am getting, Please help me resolve it**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/kutloano/Documents/Prog/ml/getData.py", line 24, in <module>
housing = load_housing_data()
File "/Users/kutloano/Documents/Prog/ml/getData.py", line 22, in load_housing_data
return pd.read_csv(csv_path)
File "/Users/kutloano/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", 
line 702, in parser_f
return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
File "/Users/kutloano/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 429, in _read
parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
File "/Users/kutloano/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 895, in __init__
self._make_engine(self.engine)
File "/Users/kutloano/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1122, in _make_engine
self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
File "/Users/kutloano/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1853, in __init__
self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 387, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__
File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 705, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._setup_parser_source
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File b'datasets/housing/housing.csv' does not exist: b'datasets/housing/housing.csv'
```

Comment: Are you sure that you extracted the file, and that the extracted file is at that location? It looks like it isn't...

Comment: My if statement was meant to create the directory but when I run the code no directory is created.

Comment: Okay. I managed to find my problem, I didn't run the function. After running it I get a 404 error

Comment: `HOUSING_URL` doesn't contain a path delimiter between the `master` and `datasets`

Comment: After adding the delimiter I get a error 500

Comment: I managed to get it fixed, the tgz_path was giving me a error, so I had to include the whole path within the urlretrieve method